# How does one cast while moving?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Is there a way to cast spells during a movement? Or rather, a way to be able to move both before and after casting a spell, as long as you do not exceed your max movement and have the actions to spare? Much like the Shot on the Run feat, except for spellcasters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two feats that allow movement before and after casting a spell.

- The feat **Spell on the Run** (*Polyhedron* #159 24) has, among other prerequisites, the feat [Shot on the Run](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#shot-on-the-run) (*Player's Handbook* 100). The Spell on the Run feat *is* the feat Shot on the Run except that a spell that has a casting time of 1 standard action or less can be cast between the creature's movements. However, a DM, may limit the feat's availability exclusively to [githyanki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Githyanki).
- The feat **Mobile Spellcasting** (*Complete Adventurer* 211) has far easier prerequisites to meet, requiring only 8 ranks in the skill Concentration. Its benefit is a little more complicated:

  > You can make a special Concentration check (DC 20 + spell level) when casting a spell. If the check succeeds, you can cast the spell and move up to your speed as a single standard action. (You can’t use this ability to cast a spell that takes longer than 1 standard action to cast.) If the check fails, you lose the spell and fail to cast it, just as if you had failed a Concentration check to cast the spell defensively.
  >
  > You still provoke attacks of opportunity for casting spells from any creatures who threaten you at any point of your movement. You can cast defensively while using this feat, but doing so increases the Concentration DC to 25 + spell level.

  For most casters, this feat will be the preferred method unless magic items, spells, or other effects are employed instead. Most casters maximize their ranks in the Concentration skill anyway, after all.

Note that other methods can essentially duplicate the effects of these feats, like a *belt of battle* (*Magic Item Compendium* 73) (12,000 gp; 0 lbs.), the feat Travel Devotion (*Complete Champion* 62-3), or the feat [Flyby Attack](http://dndsrd.net/monsterFeats.html#flyby-attack) (*Monster Manual* 303) if the creature possesses a fly speed.

Comment: I might recommend adding Flyby Attack to this list; fly speeds are very common at higher levels and it does the job better than Mobile Spellcasting once you have one.

Comment: @Forrestfire An excellent suggestion. Added as an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: I am surprised to see no mention of being on a mount. Although it still involves a Concentration Check, it seems even cheaper (no feat at all).

Comment: @MatthieuM. I can add it the other methods if you like. Thing is, it's really hard to control when *exactly* the spell's cast if the caster's astride a mount. Because the rules on it are so vague, we're left with [this article](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050208a) that says, "[Y]ou cast your spell when your mount has completed half its movement for the turn." So casting on a mount *is* certainly *a* possibility for before-and-after movement, but I hesitate to offer it up lest I shoulder the blame for its imprecision.